# canonical-livepatch, how does it work?

Tags: kernel, updates, xubuntu, canonical-livepatch

When I try to update/upgrade my system (`apt-get full-upgrade`):

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-85 linux-headers-4.4.0-85-generic linux-image-4.4.0-85-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-85-generic
```

And after update I got, version of linux kernel by itself:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xubuntu 4.4.0-81-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:17:06 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But Canonical Livepatch is working:

```
$ canonical-livepatch status --verbose
client-version: "7.21"
machine-id: xxx
machine-token: xxx
architecture: x86_64
cpu-model: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad  CPU   Q9550  @ 2.83GHz
last-check: 2017-07-04T10:17:04.377940173+03:00
boot-time: 2017-06-27T12:14:24+03:00
uptime: 166h21m9s
status:
- kernel: 4.4.0-81.104-generic
  running: true
  livepatch:
    checkState: checked
    patchState: applied
    version: "25.1"
    fixes: |-
      * CVE-2016-0758 LP: #158120 and others
```

Why uname is showing 4.4.0-**81**, not 4.4.0-**85**?
If canonical can update only the same kernel, is there any option to switch kernel without rebooting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/10/canonical-livepatch.html:

> The Canonical Livepatch Service is intended to address high and
>   critical severity Linux kernel security vulnerabilities

Normal updates (those you get using apt) still require system reboot to apply new kernels.

Comment: So, it is working, but not updating the number of kernel.

Comment: Correct. It will only apply kernel patches (not replace the whole kernel!) that prepared and selected by Canonical to the running kernel. It is a distinct process than apt upgrade.